# Occupation & Vocation

Tags: word-choice

I want to ask which is the more formal and common word between
"vocation" and "occupation" in British English, for example similar to: "What's your job?"

I found "vocation learnt". Is it usual to say "What's your vocation or your occupation?" or "what occupation/vocation did you learn ?" ?

[Google Ngram: job,vocation,occupation](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vocation%2Coccupation%2Cjob&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvocation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Coccupation%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjob%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: I usually hear 'what is your avocation?' A search on your part will fruitful!

Comment: Dict. tells "avocation" is an additional job / side job.

Comment: yes and researching the synonyms, antonyms and definitions of occupation and vocation will yield much!

Answer (score 1):

**Vocation** and **occupation** are two quite different words, in my experience (native BrE speaker in my 30s).

I can see why you might think they're similar, given the first words on vocation's definition at [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vocation?s=t) (emphasis mine):

> 1. **a particular occupation**, business, or profession; calling.

but you need to pay attention to the last word in that definition: **calling**, i.e. "that which someone has called me to do". If you look at the whole of the definition, you can see more about this:

> 1. a particular occupation, business, or profession; calling.
> 2. a strong impulse or inclination to follow a particular activity or career.
> 3. a divine call to God's service or to the Christian life.
> 4. a function or station in life to which one is called by God: *the religious vocation; the vocation of marriage.*

So "vocation" in terms of occupation means "the job that God has called me to do"; though I think the religious aspect is not consciously recognised by most people when they use it. That whole "I've been called to this" is synonymous with "I've found the job I *ought* to be doing". You'll most often hear the word "vocation" in phrases like "I've finally found my vocation!" from someone who has recently changed jobs and found that they absolutely love the new one.

As such, I'd suggest "occupation" is far more common than "vocation". And I wouldn't treat either as more "formal", I'd just note that "vocation" means "the right job for someone".

---

I've never heard of "vocation learnt". A "vocation" is something you have or find, you can't train to get it. If you've decided what job is your "vocation" then you can train for it, but many people wouldn't say that they have a vocation.

In terms of finding out what someone's job is, by far the most common phrase is "What do you do?".

In terms of learning a job, you might talk about "learning a trade", but that only applies to trade jobs, not all jobs. It's not idiomatic to say "learn an occupation", about the closest I can think of is "study for a career".

Comment: This confirms my feelings too so far. Its smiliar to the German use of "vocation". One question remains: If i want to ask an applicant for his verified finished apprenticeship. EG @ the London Chamber of Commerce. I think Job is more streetlike.

Comment: @FrankMK - I'm afraid I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "ask an applicant for his verified finished apprenticeship", but I'll try and answer. I think you have a candidate who has on his CV "Apprenticeship at the London Chamber of Commerce", but you don't know whether he was an apprentice -broker, -trader, or maybe even -doorman or -waiter. Perhaps you could say "What field was your apprenticeship in?" or "What apprenticeship did you study?" or "What career was the apprenticeship for?".

Comment: @FrankMK Be careful though because the German apprenticeship system does not exist in most other countries. Therefore there is often not a perfect 1:1 translation or even a commonly used term because the thing itself is not common. Do you mean Ausbildung, for someone who was an Azubi?

Comment: ok, we have "apprentice" as state (learning a job) = first stage of a formal occupational activity. Another one would be "Master" of ...... as a third Stage. or Professor as last/highest state. Some people telling you "my job is officer" in a bureau, but they never were apprenticed formal or graduated.

Comment: @FrankMK - So his job is "officer" but when he did his apprenticeship, the apprenticeship wasn't for "officer" it was for something else? I think I'd say "What did you do your apprenticeship in?" without bothering with the word "occupation" or "job". Also, I think SonofPingu's comment is on the mark here - you may be looking for words to describe something that doesn't really exist in the UK, and hence not in English either.

Comment: What is so uncommon of a "formal" job title ? A job that you "really" learned with all its issues and a exam with a certificate. I think this term is very importend to decide which applicant would suit the best to a vacancy.
I think asking: "Whats your formal job ?"  :-)

Comment: Sorry for stressing or "bothering", but it is part of my higher business examination and I want to clarify that point. Your comments are always wellcome.

Comment: @FrankMK - There is so such thing as a "formal job" vs an "actual job" in the UK. You can ask someone what their qualifications are. If you're not interested in school and university qualifications, you can ask "What are your professional qualifications?". But many people don't have these, and they're not required in most professions in the UK. You learn far more *doing* a job than you ever learn in studies about this, but just doing a job doesn't often lead to a qualification in the UK.

Comment: @ Andy, yes that makes clear why they teach in the 1. exam the necessary of a job reference or a recommendation from your last employer. We were trained to write those recommendations.

Comment: My instinct, although I haven't done the research to back it up, is that *vocation* is also used quite a lot with reference to jobs like nursing where there's an assumption that people are doing it out of a sense of duty or service to others rather than for the money. (This supplements your description of doing it out of a love of the job *per se*, and is consistent with your phrase "*the job I* ought *to be doing*").